# How to share Excel JS Add-in for testing?

Tags: javascript, excel, deployment, office-js, office-addins

I'm developing Excel JS Add-in using Visual Studio, I can run it locally on both desktop and web based version of Excel.
I need to share it with my client for testing and feedback but non of the official deploy mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish) methods works.

Comment: Which one are you using `localhost` or `*.nginx.com` in the manifest file?

Comment: Would it suit your needs to have that client's IT pro use this tool? [Web Add-in Sideloader](https://github.com/davecra/WebAddinSideloader)

Comment: That was what I was looking for, I got a web server and now it's working fine.